# Safari Timeout when using asynchronous call in jquery even though using async true

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I am using jQuery in front end to send the ajax request and using anonymous  to make recursive call back and it's working fine in  google chrome and mozilla and in safari giving me request time out.

here is my code snippet

```
var ajaxVal=function(i){ 

                var obj={
                        clientName: clientName,
                        accessType:accessType,
                        processProgress:processList[i]
                }

                $.ajax({
                url: 'Url.html',
                type: 'POST',
                async:true,
                data:{
                        reqData:JSON.stringify(obj)
                     },
                async: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    var data=JSON.parse(result);
                    if(i==processList.length-1){

                            if(finalFlag){
                            $('#statusModal .popUp-text').text("Client Created Successfully.");
                            $('#statusModal .popUp-text').addClass("success");
                            $("#statusModal").modal('show');

                            }
                            });
                         }, 1000);

                    }else if(data.success==true|| data.success=="true"){
                         var Progresschart=eachProgressList*(i+1);

                        $("#myBar").animate({width: Progresschart+"%" }, "slow",function(){
                            if(jVal<processList.length){
                                jVal++;
                                ajaxVal(jVal);
                            }
                        });

                    }else{
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#statusModal .popUp-text').text("Client Creation Fail.");
                            $('#statusModal .popUp-text').addClass("fail");
                            $("#statusModal").modal('show');
                            finalFlag=false;
                         }, 1000);
                    }
                },error: function(){

                },timeout: 30000

            });
            }
        ajaxVal(jVal);
```

Comment: You have `async:true` and `async:false` at the same time.

Comment: i changed to async true but still in chrome  showing  in network canceled request because my third request taking some 40 sec